# Pandas: Quick random negative sampling

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame full of positive samples and context features for a given user:

```
   target  user  cashtag  sector  industry
0       1   170     4979       3        70
1       1   170     5539       3        70
2       1   170     7271       3        70
3       1   170     7428       3        70
4       1   170      686       7       139
```

where a positive sample is a `user` having interacted with a `cashtag` and is denoted by `target` = 1.

What is a quick way for me to generate negative samples in the ratio 1:2 (+ve:-ve) for each interaction, denoted by `target` = -1?

**EDIT:** Sample for clarity below (for the first two positive samples)

```
   target  user  cashtag  sector  industry
0       1   170     4979       3        70
1      -1   170     3224       7       181
2      -1   170     4331       7       180
3       1   170     5539       3        70
4      -1   170     9304       4        59
5      -1   170     3833       6       185
```

For instance, for each cashtag a user has interacted with, I'd like to pick at random 2 other cashtags that they haven't interacted with and add them as negative samples to the dataframe; effectively increasing the size of the dataframe to 3 times its original size.

It would also be helpful to check if the negative sample hasn't already been entered for that `user`, `cashtag` combination.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `nlp` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: its not clear, could display a complete sample with the expected output

Comment: @Frenchy I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @kuomi, if i understant, for each positive target = 1, you want to add 2 rows with a cashtag, industry and sector values created randomnly? so what are the values down and up for each category? and the 2 new rows created must be after the row or their  positions are not important?

Comment: @Frenchy The index does not matter, however I'd want to keep the row information (cashtag, sector, industry) together and map it to say, user 170 as an item they have **not** interacted with, with a target of -1. (for each positive target)

Comment: @kuomi, i have found a solution, hope i have understood you, either say me..

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
data="""
target  user  cashtag  sector  industry
 1   170     4979       3        70
 1   170     5539       3        70
 1   170     7271       3        70
 1   170     7428       3        70
 1   170      686       7       139
 """
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
cashtag = df['cashtag'].values.tolist()

#function to randomize some numbers
def randomnumber(v):
    return np.random.randint(v, size=1)

def addNewRow(x):
    for i in range(2):                   #add 2 new rows
        cash = cashtag[0]
        while cash in cashtag:           #check if cashtag already used
            cash = randomnumber(5000)[0] #random number  between 0 and 5000
        cashtag.append(cash)
        sector = randomnumber(10)[0]
        industry = randomnumber(200)[0]
        df1.loc[df1.shape[0]] = [-1, x.user, cash, sector, industry]


df.apply(lambda x: addNewRow(x), axis=1)

df = df.append(df1).reset_index()
print(df)
```

---

output:

```
    index target user cashtag sector industry
0       0      1  170    4979      3       70
1       1      1  170    5539      3       70
2       2      1  170    7271      3       70
3       3      1  170    7428      3       70
4       4      1  170     686      7      139
5       0     -1  170     544      2       59
6       1     -1  170    3202      8      165
7       2     -1  170    2673      0       40
8       3     -1  170    4021      1       30
9       4     -1  170     682      6        3
10      5     -1  170    2446      1       80
11      6     -1  170    4026      9      193
12      7     -1  170    4070      9      197
13      8     -1  170    2900      1       57
14      9     -1  170    3287      0       21
```

The new random rows are put at the end of dataframe